# Fourier Series; odd and even half-range expansion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I have some standard Fourier series questions which I cannot solve. My fourier series is defined like this:

$$s(x)=\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos (nx) + b_n \sin (nx))$$

For $f(t) = \pi - t$ ,   where $0<t<\pi$,

q1) find the $b_n$ coefficient of the odd expansion,

q2) find the $a_0$ and $a_n$ coefficients of the even expansion.

1. [my attempt](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282/pi%29%28int%20from%200%20to%20pi%20of%20%28pi-t%29sin%28nt%29dt%29); which is apparently wrong
2. I got $a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1-\cos(\pi\,n)}{n^2}\ ,\quad a_0=\pi$. Don't know whether it's wrong or not.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Ad q1): Your attempt is correct, but neither Wolfram Alpha nor you seem to be aware that $\sin(\pi n)=0$ for all natural $n$.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that solved the problem. I replaced cos(nt) with (-1)^n and the program accepted it too